# Do the rules of ordering and offset apply to columns which are stacked?

Tags: bootstrap-4

Experimenting with Bootstrap4 (beta) and ordering of elements. I have a single row and I want to display 4 pieces of text (S,M,L,XL). I have divided the row into 6 columns for all screen sizes using col-6. I suppose, bootstrap will pick `S`, put in row1col1, pick `M`, put it in row1col7.

How will bootstrap interpret location of `L` and `XL`? What are the column numbers of `L` and `XL`? Note that all of these belong to single row even though the table shows 2 rows.

```
<style>
        .my-border {
            border:solid;
        }
    </style>
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 my-border"> Small </div>
            <div class="col-6 my-border"> Medium </div>
            <div class="col-6 my-border"> Large </div>
            <div class="col-6 my-border"> X-Large </div>            
        </div>

    </div>
```

Later I added `ordering` to the code. I want that for `md` or larger devices, `M` should come before `S`, `L` and `XL` stay the same. But in the following code, even though `M` and `S` swap places, `L` and `XL` become row 1 while `M` and `S` become row 2.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 my-border order-md-6"> Small </div>
            <div class="col-6 my-border order-md-1"> Medium </div>
            <div class="col-6 my-border"> Large </div>
            <div class="col-6 my-border"> X-Large </div>            
        </div>

    </div>
```

What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 my-border order-md-4"> Small </div>
            <div class="col-6 my-border order-md-1"> Medium </div>
            <div class="col-6 my-border order-md-7"> Large </div>
            <div class="col-6 my-border order-md-10"> X-Large </div>            
        </div>
```

I suppose the way Bootstrap is working is, it first picks elements without ordering and put them in columns in FIFO manner. Then it picks all the elements with ordering element (say 1) and puts them in FIFO order. If while doing this, some other element is already in that column then Bootstrap would put this element at the end of that column.  I suppose it is important that ordering is provided for all columns to get a predictable behaviour.

More examples.
out of this is Large (no ordering, First), X-Large (no ordering, second), Medium (ordering 1), Small (ordering 4)

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 my-border order-md-4"> Small </div>
            <div class="col-6 my-border order-md-1  "> Medium </div>
            <div class="col-6 my-border "> Large </div>
            <div class="col-6 my-border "> X-Large </div>            
        </div>
```

Order of this is Medium (ordering 1, first), Large (ordering 1, second), Small (ordering 4, first), X-Large (ordering 4, second)

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 my-border order-md-4"> Small </div>
            <div class="col-6 my-border order-md-1  "> Medium </div>
            <div class="col-6 my-border order-md-1"> Large </div>
            <div class="col-6 my-border order-md-4"> X-Large </div>            
        </div>
```